# OpenCV - extract rectangle from keyPoints

Tags: opencv, image-processing, knn, kdtree, flann

I have set of points after a gray frame processing.
I need to find a rectangle that has a fixed aspect ratio.
Currently, I have a simple greedy algorithm with complexity of O(n^3) which has 3 loops of points to find a reduced triangle that match the constraint of width/height ratio.
Any suggestion for fast algorithm or data structure like KDTree?